# How to use the -not switch with find2perl and File::Find

Tags: perl, find

Need some help with find2perl.  Originally I was performing the usual:

```
my @files = `find . | grep -v "*.svn"`;
```

This worked well until the source tree grew rather large, causing the above to slow down quite a bit.  So I switched to this:

```
my @files = `find . -not \( -path *.svn -prune \)`;
```

This helped a lot, but over time it too has become rather slow.

I've read here that File::Find should/would be faster than shelling out, but I can't seem to get find2perl to create the $wanted sub-routine reference for me.  It gives me the following error:

```
find2perl . -not \( -path *.svn -prune \) -print
Unrecognized switch: -not
```

Is there some other way I should be doing this?
Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-not` isn't standard option of `find`, you need to use `!`:

```
find2perl . ! \( -path '*.svn' -prune \) -print
```

Also note that you must quote `*.svn` to prevent the shell from performing split+glob on it.

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed it!  I never knew -not wasn't the standard.